# Index signature is missing in Type - AngularJS + TypeScript validation using $validators

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

I'm trying to create a directive using AngularJS 1.5 and TypeScript 1.7 so I can do some custom form validation.

[I've followed this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32333377/angularjs-typescript-add-a-customised-validators) but Typescript gives me a 'Type signature is missing in type' when I extend the ng.INgModelController

```
interface IOneItemRequiredValidator extends ng.INgModelController {
    $validators: {
        oneItemRequired(modelValue: any, viewValue: any) : boolean;
    };
}
```

I've checked $validators and it's of type IModelValidators, with the below signature:

```
interface IModelValidators {
    [index: string]: (modelValue: any, viewValue: any) => boolean;
}
```

so I tried to follow that and now TypeScript is not complaning, but when I try to access the new property of the $validators object it can't find it.

```
interface IOneItemRequiredValidator extends ng.INgModelController {
    $validators: {
        [oneItemRequired: string]:  (modelValue: any, viewValue: any) => boolean;
    };
}


angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('oneItemRequired', () => {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attributes: ng.IAttributes, controller: IOneItemRequiredValidator) => {
                controller.$validators.oneItemRequired = (modelValue, viewValue) => {
                        return viewValue !== null && viewValue !== undefined && viewValue.length > 0;
                    }
                }
            };
        });
```

[image: oneItemRequired does not exist in the $validators object]

Am I wrongly declaring my new IOneItemRequiredValidator interface? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use Angular 1 with TypeScript but generally speaking, in TypeScript, the name you give to these doesn't make a difference at all. You are just saying that you accept any extra property not named in the interface.

This means that the actual Angular declaration file is the one that should have added this bit in `IModelValidators` declaration. See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) for details.

The problem with the old way is that the type of the object with a single function `oneItemRequired` is not compatible with the `IModelValidators` type.

You can fix that in one of two ways:

(1) Just put back the indexer, like:

```
interface IOneItemRequiredValidator extends INgModelController {
    $validators: {
        oneItemRequired(modelValue : any, viewValue : any) : boolean;
        [otherProps: string]:  (modelValue: any, viewValue: any) => boolean;
    };
}
```

[A simple non-Angular example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IOneItemRequiredValidator%20extends%20ng.INgModelController%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%24validators%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20oneItemRequired(modelValue%20%3A%20any%2C%20viewValue%20%3A%20any)%20%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%09%09%5BotherProps%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%20(modelValue%3A%20any%2C%20viewValue%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20testValidation(x%20%3A%20IOneItemRequiredValidator)%20%7B%0D%0A%09x.%24validators.oneItemRequired%20%3D%20function(x%2C%20y)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20true%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Anamespace%20ng%20%7B%0D%0A%09export%20interface%20IModelValidators%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%5Bindex%3A%20string%5D%3A%20(modelValue%3A%20any%2C%20viewValue%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09export%20interface%20INgModelController%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%24validators%20%3A%20IModelValidators%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

(2) Extend the interface manually, like:

```
interface IOneItemRequiredNgModelValidators
    extends ng.IModelValidators {
        oneItemRequired(modelValue : any, viewValue : any) : boolean;       
    }

interface IOneItemRequiredValidator extends ng.INgModelController {
    $validators: IOneItemRequiredNgModelValidators
}
```

[A simple non-Angular example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IOneItemRequiredNgModelValidators%0D%0A%09extends%20ng.IModelValidators%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20oneItemRequired(modelValue%20%3A%20any%2C%20viewValue%20%3A%20any)%20%3A%20boolean%3B%09%09%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IOneItemRequiredValidator%20extends%20ng.INgModelController%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%24validators%3A%20IOneItemRequiredNgModelValidators%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20testValidation(x%20%3A%20IOneItemRequiredValidator)%20%7B%0D%0A%09x.%24validators.oneItemRequired%20%3D%20function(x%2C%20y)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20true%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Anamespace%20ng%20%7B%0D%0A%09export%20interface%20IModelValidators%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%5Bindex%3A%20string%5D%3A%20(modelValue%3A%20any%2C%20viewValue%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09export%20interface%20INgModelController%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%24validators%20%3A%20IModelValidators%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

This first one is less code that only aims to serve the tool really, except it's a little hacky. The 2nd one feels cool, but it's more just for the tool. So, I'll let you pick :)

Let me know if they work for you.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks @Meligy for taking the time to put such comprehensive answer and adding the example in the playground. I ended up going with the second option as it looks clearer. It's now working a treat!. cheers